# When speaking, how to link "barged her" in "She barged her way through the shopping crowds"?

Tags: pronunciation

She barged her way through the shopping crowds.

The complete form should be [bʌdʒd hər]. I'm not sure in order to link those two words when speaking, it should be [bʌdʒ ər] or [bʌdʒd ər]? Thanks.

Comment: Not [bʌdʒd hər]. That's _budged her_. The verb you're looking for is [bardʒd]. Even in RP it'd be [ba:dʒd hə]. As far as /fæspitʃrulz/ are concerned, initial pronoun /h/s are virtually always dropped, especially after consonants, **most** especially after triple-obstruent consonant clusters like /dʒd/. The final /d/, though, is necessary to mark past tense. So  [bardʒdərweθruðəʃapɪŋkrawdz].

Comment: WADR, why not post it as the answer?

Comment: I would pronounce the H at least half the time, but it would be less pronounced than usual.  However, as a person who does not hear well in one ear, I am someone who values speaking clearly.  I'm probably in the minority in the U.S.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's how i'd pronounce it:

> ʃəbɑːɾdʒdəʳwe(ɪ)θɾuːðəʃɒpɪŋkɾɑʊdz

P.S. The Brits would drop all the Rs in there. Hope it helps

Comment: There needs to be spaces, otherwise it looks like one long word. I disagree the Brits would drop all the Rs, you're thinking of the [rhotic R](http://english.stackexchange.com/search?q=rhotic+R) which is heard more often in the States, but I can hear the R in *through*, and the R in *crowds* is always pronounced in BrEng.